# Downloading Info in Mozilla firefox Add-ons

Tags: javascript, firefox, download, firefox-addon

I am trying to create a mozilla firefox add-on in which I am trying to get the Downloading Info  of the browser .... As I am new to it that's why don't know how to do it? any link would be appreciated........

Comment: Can you explain a little more please. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean that while making the extension I need info about the files that the browser has downloaded ....

Comment: Oh I see, so you want to go through the users download history?

Comment: @Notidart yup,can you help me with that?

Comment: I don't know anything about it, but this is a good starting point: [mxr](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/search?string=nsIDownloadManagerUI&find=&findi=&filter=^[^\0]*%24&hitlimit=&tree=mozilla-release])

Comment: ill try to figure it out too though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox uses [`Downloads.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm) these days. Note that this is a `Promise` based async API for the most part, so you really want to consider using [`Task.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Task.jsm).

Example:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm");

Task.spawn(function logDownloads() {
  try {
    let list = yield Downloads.getList(Downloads.ALL);
    let downloads = yield list.getAll();
    for (let d of downloads) {
      console.log(d.source.url + " -> " + d.target.path);
    }
  }
  catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to direct all the pdf files to a separate directories using the extension...I have written the code to direct every file to /new directory which I will modify for PDF files...but it doesn't work...  Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm")
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm");

Promise<Download> createDownload("/new");